# Interrupts for Data Ready pin

Tags: c, embedded, interrupt

I have an external signal coming in from a device (AFE - Analog Front End) which I need to use as an interrupt to perform a task.
The signal is active low, and it goes low whenever data is ready to be read from the device. It goes high ODR times (where ODR is the output data rate) in a second. I need to use it as a logic 0 level interrupt, reading data from the device using my K53 Kinetis microcontroller from Freescale. I am communicating via SPI with the microcontroller as master and AFE as slave

The issue is, only when I send NOPs to the AFE do I get data from the device, due to the two way nature of SPI. So unless I send NOP commands, I do not get the DRDY (data ready) signal from the AFE, which I must use as the interrupt - but, the DRDY signal tells me when I read data from the device (Giving NOP = giving clock cycles in which to receive data from the AFE. Thus, reading data = giving NOP commands).

So far, what I've done is given a few NOPs just after configuring the device to output data and enabling the interrupt - so that some data can come in and th eDRDY signal can come in. Without the NOPs, the DRDY signal is always low and I am stuck forever in the ISR. With the few NOPs before the main while, DRDY is generated, and within the ISR, I give more NOPs so that the DRDY signal can be sustained.

However, using the same code, it works sometimes, but sometimes it still gets stuck in the ISR. It is inconsistent, making me think that there are some serious timing issues here.

My code looks like this:

```
enable_irq(91);  
//this tells the device to output frames of data at ODR
reg_read_adas1000(0x40000000); 

for (i=0;i<1000;i++) 
//few NOPs - the slave in line is 0 
reg_read_adas1000(0x00000000); 

while (j<9900){
  asm("nop");
  j++; 
}
```

The ISR :

```
void porte_isr(void) {
  //giving NOP and storing data obtained from device in an array
  data_adas1000[inter_iter_flag]=reg_read_adas1000(0x00000000);        

  //increment counter
  inter_iter_flag++;

  //break out of the program at a suitable length of array
  if (inter_iter_flag >= 9900)
    disable_irq(91); 
  PORTE_ISFR = 0xFFFFFFFF; //Clear Flags  
}
```

Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Note: You should only use explicit assembler code if needed. For the ARM Cortex, the CMSIS headers already provide a NOP instruction (`__NOP()` - might be lowercase, just check).

Comment: What does the debugger say? Where exactly is it stuck? That "ISR" is not the original ISR; it is called from somewhere; what does that do? Please clarify your question and add, what you have tried so far!

Comment: I added appropriate tagging to your question (it might get a lot more users to notice it this way).

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that you'd only get a DRDY signal after sending NOP. The very reason for a DRDY signal is so you don't need to poll for data. Can yo give a link or a part number for the AFE ?

Comment: The AFE is ADAS1000 from Analog Devices, datasheet : http://www.analog.com/en/products/analog-to-digital-converters/ad-converters/adas1000.html

Comment: @Olaf , I have a while loop in the main which calls another SpO2 AFE device, and when it is interrupted when DRDY is low by the AFE-ECG device,  it goes into the ISR to read data from the ECG device.

Comment: @RafaelDazcal , DRDY signal goes high again when the microcontroller has finished reading the frame. Thus, only when I give a NOP (i.e. read to register at address 0x00 in the ECG-AFE), the SDI of the ECG-AFE is inactive and the microcontroller gets the frame data from the ECG-AFE. I have tried enabling conversion and frames and just sitting in an infinite while loop that does nothing, I do not get the DRDY signal.

Comment: @Olaf , I have a while loop in the main which calls another SpO2 AFE device, and when it is interrupted when DRDY is low by the AFE-ECG device,  it goes into the ISR to read data from the ECG device.
I have tried checking the value of the counters (I am incrementing one counter in the ISR and one inthe while loop in the main function) in the debug mode, Sometimes it increments both alternately, but mostly it first increments fully in the ISR (I have a check in the ISR- once the counter reaches a particular value, it disables interrupts and goes back to main program) and main counter increments

Comment: @Meow: That does not answer my question. Please step in a debugger. The Cortex-M can be pretty good debugged, even in interrupt handlers (you might have to set some peripherals to auto-halt if the CPU halt, see the documentation from freescale and ARM). It is not possible to provide a simple answer without more information, as the problem might be the AFE configuration, the Kinetis setup, hardware or the software not shown. So I can just give you tips how to find the fault yourself. This requires - apparently - major effort from your side.